# Inverter connected appliances not working when mains are on

Tags: electrical, inverter

I've the following inverter:

**Model**: Sukam Shiny

**URL**: [Inverter pics](https://upsinverterinfo.com/home-upsinverter-back-panel-switch-how-to-use-it.html) (1st model on the page)

The problem is that even with the mains on, I'm facing two issues:

1. Inverter runs in Battery mode (Backup)
2. All appliances that are connected via the inverter stop working

This problem started happening last night when there was a power cut for about 10 mins. As soon the power went out, inverter switched to battery mode and appliances (fans/light) stopped working (even though they should have kept running)

And then when the power came back, the inverter stayed in that mode. Only when I switched off the inverter then the fans/light started working.

So basically it's like I no longer have the inverter facility at my home.

I'm not very much technical with this stuff but I'll list out whatever info that I know of.

1. Location: India
2. Operating voltage: 220-240v
3. Battery has 6 cells (all have been re-filled with distilled water)
4. Some corrosion was visible in one of the wire plate which I cleared
   out with a brush
5. Inverter is set to W-UPS mode
6. Charging mode: LA (10 amp)
7. Fuse seems to be okay
8. Strangely, I do not see a reset button on the inverter

So in summary, with the main power on the appliances work only when I turn off the inverter otherwise the appliances do not work and inverter remains in battery mode.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So it sounds like there is some issue.with this inverter.  You've only quoted specification for the device, however, and not reported any actual measurements of it in operation.  Using a voltmeter it might be helpful to take some voltage measurements.

Answer (score 0):

That you have filled the battery and it has had time to charge turn the main to the house off and see if the inverter kicks in. One low cell in the battery can cause the system to fail. If the system works I would keep an eye on the water level and age of the battery some systems put a constant trickle to the battery not a float charge. A constant charge boils the water off and will reduce the life of the battery although it appears to be charged. The only way to know for sure is to test it if it only last for a few seconds or minutes not close to what it used to do it’s time for a new battery. Several of my large inverters or battery backups Had this same issue so test it to see if the battery is still good as my guess with the info provided this was the cause.

If you need a new battery , it kicks in for a minute or 5 when it used to run for an hour , make sure to get a deep cycle battery. I use marine deep cycle starting batteries they tend to last the longest , I go as large that will fit in the case this can give additional minutes of run time.